# Evaluation of XPath changes with different environments

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xerces

I have a standalone java project in which i am evaluation XPath from my xml file and it giving the right result. 
When i integrated my source code into an application deployed on websphere 7, the result is not ok anymore. 
After verification, i found that in the first case (standalone project) the Document is well-built (all the nodes from the root are recognized) and in the second case (source code added in the deployed app on WS 7) the root node is missing in the Document.
I worked with the same implementation of "DocumentBuilderFactory" in both cases and the problem persists.
This is the code i used :

```
    domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    xmlContent = new byte[inputStream.available()];
    inputStream.read(xmlContent); 
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlContent);
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    document = documentBuilder  .parse(bais);
    xPATH = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
```

The implementation of DomFactory is : "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl" from the jar xerces-impl.1.5

Any ideas would be helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The InputStream.read(byte[]) method [*might or might not*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read-byte:A-) fill the array passed to it.  At first, you were lucky;  just because the code worked once doesn't mean it was guaranteed to work every time or on every platform.

The other problem is that [the contract of the InputStream.available() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available--) specifically states:

> Note that while some implementations of `InputStream` will return the total number of bytes in the stream, many will not. It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream.

In your case, there is a pretty simple solution.  You already have an InputStream.  Do not read it into a byte array; delete all uses of `xmlContent`, `bais`, and available().  Parse the original InputStream instead:

```
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
document = documentBuilder.parse(inputStream);
xPATH = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
```

Comment: The problem is solved. You were right, the problem was related to the content of the InputStream. In the second case, the IS is being parsed throught two kind of parsers which alterated its content (the root node wasn't there).